# Left joining and subqueries with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join

Here is my draft code which will fail based on placement, location of parenthesis and assigning a name to each of the tables.  I am unsure of how to create a nested query with a left join when joining on multiple tables.

Any suggestions for how to rewrite the below code is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #1 ;  
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #2 ;  
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #3 ;  


SELECT *  FROM   nwh_analytics.dbo.km_cmr_table a 

left join (
select  
   b.prov_id + b.prov_site_num as prov,
   count(distinct b.claim_num) total_claims_billed,
   sum(b.paid) as total_dollars_paid

into    
#1 -- drop table #1 

from    
datawarehouse.dbo.claims b
where   
dos >= '2017-01-01'
and fee_sched like 'tup%'
and a.code = b.CPT_CODE

group by    
   prov_id + prov_site_num)

   on a.code = b.CPT_CODE


Select * From nwh_analytics.dbo.km_cmr_table a 

left join(
select  
d.contract_id,
d.contract_legal_name,
b.prov_id + b.prov_site_num as prov,
c.prov_full_name,
count(distinct b.claim_num) as claims_with_new_codes,
sum(b.paid) as paid_for_claims_with_new_codes,
e.total_claims_billed,
e.total_dollars_paid

into    
#2

from    
datawarehouse.dbo.claims b 
join datawarehouse.dbo.providers c
on b.prov_id = c.prov_id
join datawarehouse.dbo.providers_site d
on b.prov_id + b.prov_site_num =c.prov_id + d.site_num
join #1 e
on b.prov_id + b.prov_site_num = e.prov

where   
b.dos >= '2017-01-01'
and b.fee_sched like 'tup%')
a.code = b. FEE_CPT



Select * From nwh_analytics.dbo.km_cmr_table a 

left join(select    
c.contract_id,
c.contract_legal_name,
a.prov_id + a.prov_site_num as prov,
b.prov_full_name,
a.claim_num,
a.line_num,
a.dos,
a.cpt_code,
cd.cpt_desc,
a.proc_mod1,
a.proc_mod2,
a.billed,
a.allowed,
a.paid,
a.deny_code,
a.paid_date,
a.Fee_Sched

into    
#3

from    
    datawarehouse.dbo.claims a 
    join datawarehouse.dbo.providers b
    on a.prov_id = b.prov_id
    join datawarehouse.dbo.providers_site c
    on a.prov_id + a.prov_site_num = c.prov_id + c.site_num
    join datawarehouse.dbo.cpt_codes cd
    on a.cpt_code = cd.cpt_cd

  where 
   a.dos >= '2017-01-01'
   and a.fee_sched like 'tup%')
   on a.Code = b. Fee_CPT
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `INTO #n` clauses?   You can't do a SELECT INTO as a subquery (or derived table) to an outer SELECT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am creating temp tables and dropping them.  I am not sure how to solve for that.

Comment: You are not explaining what you want to do, you are just giving some unexplained broken code that doesn't do what you want. It is not even clear what the inputs and outputs of your desired process is. Please edit to be clear. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to create TEMP tables, then you just need to rearrange the queries like this.   I will use the first as an example, and you can apply the same logic to the others:

```
SELECT * 
into  #1 -- drop table #1  
FROM   nwh_analytics.dbo.km_cmr_table a 
left join (
select  
   CPT_CODE,
   prov_id + prov_site_num as prov,
   count(distinct claim_num) total_claims_billed,
   sum(paid) as total_dollars_paid
from    
datawarehouse.dbo.claims 
where   
dos >= '2017-01-01'
and fee_sched like 'tup%'
group by    
   CPT_CODE, prov_id + prov_site_num) b
   on a.code = b.CPT_CODE
```

Comment: Thank you.  Something is not working, could it be the alias after the table name and end of left join within and after the parenthesis?

Comment: You can't select into a temp table when two fields have the same name. Is it possible this is the case? BTW you never should use select * when you have a join because you are returning repeated data and that affects performance. Plus you would have seen if you had two columns with the same name. If it is not that, then what is the error you get with this code?

Comment: It was the a-b condition in the where clause of the subquery.   I moved it to the JOIN condition.   Try my current code.   (Actually I removed it since it was already in the JOIN condition, so it was just redundant in the WHERE clause.)   Wait there is one more problem..

Comment: CPT_CODE wasn't exposed in the Select list in the subquery, so it couldn't be used in the JOIN condition.  I have fixed that as well.   Try it now.

Comment: I'm sorry, where is the code fixed?  In the original example provided?

Comment: Yes, I modified the code in my answer, rather than adding a second code example.   Haven't you tried it?

Comment: My apologies, thank you for the clarification that worked!  How do I apply that same logic to the second select statement where there are three additional tables to join to?  Do I give the subquery a different alias?

Comment: As long as each of the tables/subqueries has a different alias within the SELECT, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you were using the table alias b from the subquery to connect using on a.code = b.CPT_CODE. Can you just pull the cpt_code from inside the subquery instead.

```
SELECT *
  FROM nwh_analytics.dbo.km_cmr_table a 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT cpt_code,
                    prov_id + b.prov_site_num AS prov,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT claim_num) total_claims_billed,
                    SUM(paid) AS total_dollars_paid
               INTO #1
               FROM datawarehouse.dbo.claims
              WHERE dos >= '2017-01-01'
                AND fee_sched like 'tup%'
              GROUP BY cpt_code,
                       prov_id + prov_site_num) b
    ON a.code = b.cpt_code
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow?

Comment: I would like to edit your #2 and #3 but I do not know which table fee_cpt is coming from.

Comment: The table is datawarehouse.dbo.claims.  I am definitely doing something wrong, it has been running for over three hours

Comment: The final code that has tables 1-3 does not produce any output as of yet, it was at three hours and still trying to process.